# Let M be a finitely generated A-module and $φ : M → A^n$ a surjective homomorphism. Then $\ker φ$ is finitely generated

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence, direct-sum

Question 2.12 in Atiyah and MacDonald is similar to this:
Let M be a finitely generated A-module and $φ : M \longrightarrow A^n$
a surjective homomorphism. Show $\ker φ$ is finitely generated.

I like the solution posted here because it is short: https://users.math.msu.edu/users/ruiterj2/Math/Documents/Fall%202018/Commutative%20Algebra/Commutative%20Algebra%20Homework%202.pdf

Proof. Since $A^n$ is a free, and hence projective, A-module, the short exact sequence
$0 \longrightarrow \ker φ \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow A^n \longrightarrow 0$
splits, so $M \cong A^n ⊕ \ker φ$. Since $M$ and $A^n$ are finitely generated, so is $\ker φ$.

I understand the short exact sequence says the second function is 1-1 and the third, $φ$, is onto which we know from the problem statement, and this sequence is similar to the rank-nullity theorem - and the implication that $\ker φ$ is finitely generated, but how can $M \cong A^n ⊕ \ker φ$?

$\ker φ$ is a submodule of M so how can M be isomorphic to a direct sum of the free module $A^n$ and $\ker φ$

Comment: The sequence splits because $A^n$ is projective. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the direct sum of two $A$-modules $P,Q$ is:
$$P\oplus Q=\{(p,q)\mid p\in P, q\in Q\}$$
So $A^n\oplus \ker\varphi$ can be thought of as the set of ordered pairs $(a,\phi)$, with $a\in A^n$ and $\phi\in\ker\varphi$.

Can you now see the isomorphism with $M$?

Comment: Thanks @Luke Derry, is the elements isomorphic to $M$ in $A^n$ pairs $(a,ϕ)$ and those elements $b \in A^n$ that are not isomorphic mapped to $(b, x)$ where $x \notin ker( ϕ)$ ?

Comment: @EndreMoen no, you can think of it as saying $M$ is made up of copies of $A^n$, one for each $\phi\in\text{ker}\varphi$.

Comment: so if $kerφ = {0}$ so there is only 1 element then M is made up of just one copy of $A^n$ ?

Comment: @EndreMoen Yes, since in that case $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You can either think of this as the genuine definition of $A^n$ being projective, or an equivalent condition.

As stated in the Wikipedia link provided in the comments, a module $P$ is projective if and only if every short exact sequence of the form

$$0 \rightarrow M \xrightarrow{f} N \xrightarrow{g} P \rightarrow 0$$

*splits*. That is, there exists a *section*
$$h:P \rightarrow N$$ such that
$g \circ h: P \rightarrow P = \text{Id}_P$.

Now, this does not yet give you exactly what you need. The property that $N \cong M \oplus P$ does follow from this, though. You should treat this deduction as an exercise. Try to construct a map $M \oplus P \rightarrow N$ (there is an obvious way to do this, given the existence of the section $h:P \rightarrow N$), and then show that this is an isomorphism.

In general, not all short exact sequences split; that's what is special here (and indeed, what is special about projective modules).

Comment: Thanks @Matt ! Is $f:M⊕N⟶P$ defined as  $f(0,n)↦p$ ?

Comment: No, that is not a map you're trying to define. You want a map $f:M \oplus P \rightarrow N$ :)

Comment: You want a map $\phi:M \oplus P \rightarrow N$. It needs to take a pair $(m,p)$ to some element $\phi(m,p) \in N$. You have two maps already, $f:M \rightarrow N$ and $h:P \rightarrow N$ (where the second of these is the section that you know exists because the short exact sequence splits). 

Can you see how to combine those two maps into one map? I won't tell you what it is, but for a hint, perhaps people would denote it $(f + h):M \oplus P \rightarrow N$.

It then remains to show that this map is an isomorphism - you would use the respective properties of $f$ and $h$ to show this.

Comment: Thanks @Matt ! Is it $(f + h)(m, p) = f(m) +_N h(p) = n_1 + n_2$ ? And since $Im(h)$ is $\ker  φ$ in the example, the mapping becomes: $(f + h)(m, p) = f(m) +_N \ker(p) = n_1 + 0 = n_1$ ?

Comment: So then we have the SES $$0 \rightarrow M \xrightarrow{φ} A^n \xrightarrow{\ker φ} \ker φ \rightarrow 0$$ So $\ker φ$ is onto, and we need that $\ker φ$ is 1-1 to show it has an inverse. Then the isomorphism can be shown by showing the identity mapping $φ^-1(φ(a, p ) = (a,p)$, $a \in A^n, p \in ker φ$ ?